# What is Request Payload?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, payload

I am trying to upload an uploaded file from an html form to aws s3 and I am struggling with signing the request. For the first part of the request I need to concatenate some values together to make a string "CanonicalRequest":

```
CanonicalRequest =
  HTTPRequestMethod + '\n' +
  CanonicalURI + '\n' +
  CanonicalQueryString + '\n' +
  CanonicalHeaders + '\n' +
  SignedHeaders + '\n' +
  HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload))
```

This is what I have so far:

```
let CanonicalRequest = "Post" + '\n' +
          "/" + '\n' +
          "" + '\n' +
          "content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\n host:s3.amazonaws.com\n; x-amz-date:" + Time3 + "\n" + '\n' +
          "content-type;host;x-amz-date" + '\n' +
```

I think this is right so far but I may be completely wrong. I have no idea what the "RequestPayload" is. The only thing I have found suggests that it is the body of the html, but that would include the form and therefore the signature itself so that does not work. Does anybody understand what it is and how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use a difficult way to upload your file... AWS provide a library to interact easily with S3

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const S3 = new AWS.S3()
```

Then you can call `S3.putObject` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Comment: The file upload has to be done in an html element that does not work with nodes, so either I need to a way to get the file out of the element and then use that node or I need to do it with the signature.

Comment: You use JavaScript, so even if you don't use nodejs you still can use the AWS sdk with `<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.410.0.min.js"></script>` https://aws.amazon.com/fr/sdk-for-browser/

Comment: The link you sent manly details how to do it with a Facebook application. I am not using Facebook.

Comment: You don't necessary need to use facebook, but indeed your website will need credential to connect to AWS... The best way is to log in your users with an identity provider (Facebook, Google, Cognito,...) so you can control who can access your S3 bucket. Another way to do is to "hardcode" your credential in your website which is an extremely dangerous way to process, because that mean everybody'll be able to write in your S3 bucket (I mean a hacker could use these credentials outside your website)